# SOAP: looks like we got no XML document

Tags: php, soap

Есть [подобная тема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313952/soap-looks-like-we-got-no-xml-document) у забугорных братьев.
Выбранный ответ про BOM маркировку.
Проверил, файл норм.
Да и если у отсылаемого ID тупо вычесть/прибавить 1, то все гуд.
Вот ID: 54253511
На нем случаем не ломается?

Я уже попробовал через **try** **catch** => **__getLastResponse**.
Но и тут не хотелось в **XML** преобразовываться:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error :
>   xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 26 in

Победить не удалось.

Далее пытался использовать данные классы:

```
<?php


class XSoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    const XSI_NS = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
    const _NULL_ = "xxx_replacedduetobrokephpsoapclient_xxx";

    protected $mustParseNulls = false;

    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = null)
    {
        if($this->mustParseNulls)
        {
            $this->mustParseNulls = false;
            $request = preg_replace('/<ns1:(\w+)>'.self::_NULL_.'<\/ns1:\\1>/','<ns1:$1 xsi:nil="true"/>', $request, -1, $count);

            if ($count > 0)
            {
                $request = preg_replace('/(<SOAP-ENV:Envelope )/',
                    '\\1 xmlns:xsi="'.self::XSI_NS.'" ',
                    $request);
            }
        }
        return parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
    }

    public function __call($method, $params)
    {
        foreach($params as $k => $v)
        {
            if($v === null)
            {
                $this->mustParseNulls = true;
                $params[$k] = self::_NULL_;
            }
        }
        return parent::__call($method, $params);
    }
}


class MySoapClient extends SoapClient
{
    public function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0)
    {
        $response = parent::__doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way);
        // parse $response, extract the multipart messages and so on

        //this part removes stuff
        $start=strpos($response,'<?xml');
        $end=strrpos($response,'>');
        $response_string=substr($response,$start,$end-$start+1);
        return($response_string);
    }
}


class SoapClientNG extends \SoapClient{
    public function __doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version = SOAP_1_1){
        $xml = explode("\r\n", parent::__doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version));
        $response = preg_replace( '/^(\x00\x00\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\x00\x00|\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE|\xEF\xBB\xBF)/', "", $xml[0] );
        return $response;

    }
}
```

Так же без результатов.

Надеюсь, кто то сталкивался с подобный.

Как побороть этот недуг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Коротко о погоде:

```
$params = array('ID' => $brandID, 'FormatCurrency' => 'РУБ', 'SearchCross' => $cross);
try
{
    $details = $client->GetPriceId( $params );
}
catch(SoapFault $e)
{
    $response = $client->__getLastResponse();
    $response = str_replace("&#x1A","",$response);
    $response = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', $response);
    $response = simplexml_load_string($response);

    $details = $response->Body->GetPriceIdResponse->GetPriceIdResult;
}
if( !$details ) throw new Exception("DETAILS_NOT_FOUND");
```

> Если кто то из ребят узнает свой сервис, поправьте пожалуйста

---

Ликбез

У нас в бою есть сервер, на котором стоит PHP 5.3
И я всегда сперва не нем проверяю, так как самый старенький.
В итоге пришлось запустить на другом сервере, где 5.4
И скрипт проругался уже более информативно, указав на символ **&#x1A**